# get Latlng and output in input

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Trying to output Lat and Long when you drag the google map pin, I've added a listener but it seems to be not working.

using this api: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

so getting the latlng is just an additional feature for this example but I couldn't figure it out why its not outputting the latlng in the input.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markers, 'dragstart', 'dragend', function (event) {
      document.getElementById("lat").value = event.LatLng.lat();
      document.getElementById("long").value = event.LatLng.lng();
  });

 <input id="lat" name="lat"  val="51.5000" />
 <input id="long" name="long" val="0.1167" />
```

Edit: manage to output the latLng in the field but how can I update the latLng when dragging the marker?

```
var locPositionLat = place.geometry.location.lat(),
          locPositionLng = place.geometry.location.lng();

          $('#lat').val(locPositionLat);
          $('#lng').val(locPositionLng);

google.maps.event.addListener(markers, 'dragend', function(event) {
            document.getElementById('lat').value = event.locPositionLat; 
        });
```

Marker:

```
 var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    title: place.name,
                    position: place.geometry.location,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    draggable: true
                })

                // Create a marker for each place.
                markers.push(newMarker);
```

Comment: Where in the docs are you getting your `LatLng.lat()` and `LatLng.lng()` ? Haven't used in a while but I thought I remembered the the LatLng being retrievable from the event as a static object somewhere. But then I'd expect your code to error which you do not mention happening.

Comment: What is `markers`?  Where/how are you creating your marker?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  `markers` sounds like an array, which won't work.

Comment: the `event` object hasn't got a `locPositionLat` property, that's just something you've made up as a local variable, which has no relation to the `event` which Google's `dragend` event handler returns.  Use `event.latLng.lat()` as per my answer.

Comment: Yeah figured that, just thought I could use the var but yeah. That's working now, just trying to get the postcode is another task and output it similar to latlng

Answer (score 1):

You don't combine the event listeners like that:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markers, 'dragstart', 'dragend', function (event) {
```

Just do:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markers, 'dragend', function (event) {
```

If you need to use the same function for both dragend and dragstart, create the function first and refer to it for both event listeners.

```
function updateCoords(event) {
      document.getElementById("lat").value = event.latLng.lat();
      document.getElementById("long").value = event.latLng.lng();
}

google.maps.event.addListener(markers, 'dragstart', updateCoords);
google.maps.event.addListener(markers, 'dragend', updateCoords);
```

Comment: The property of a [MouseEvent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MouseEvent) that contains the coordinates is `latLng` (not `LatLng`)

Comment: @geocodezip right enough, I should have spotted that!

Comment: see edit please, I managed to output the latLng in the field. I tried google.map.event.Lis... line in my edit but that didn't work.

Comment: @MrNew please add the code that shows how you create your markers

Comment: @duncan see the update in my original post. I managed to get the latLng when I drag the marker now, but not sure how to properly input it in the field.

Comment: newMarker.addListener('dragend', function(event) {
                console.log(event.latLng.lat())
                document.getElementById('lat').value = event.locPositionLat;
            }); I get undefined

Comment: document.getElementById("long").value = event.latLng.lng(); works, but how can I output the initial latLng when you search location then only update it when drag the marker?

Comment: Might have found my answer now. Thanks anyway. But how do I get the location postalcode?